# custom scroll bar issue in chrome and IE

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome, operating-system

Here is the link for the folder https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yzz1m3vxhsuj71d/i3MBbDjwgn

The scroll bar is working fine in all the browsers in my PC but it is not working in chrome and IE of few other computers.

I tested in a machine which has windows xp, it was nt working in tat system (chrome and IE but it is fine in Firefox there).

Comment: I think that's the wrong link?!

Comment: I think you should login to your dropbox account to download the folder

Comment: The folder '/public/wrap' does not exist.

Comment: To get the public link: Click on the chain icon, on the right side!

Comment: Pls check the updated link in my question

Comment: To get higher quality answers I recommend to use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). But i will take look though ;-)

Comment: As there are multiple js files used, I cant create fiddle for that. So that I have provided the folder

Comment: You can! On the left side is a menu item, called `Add Ressources` :-P

Comment: even for that i need to upload the files in some site and provide the link. Compare to that I felt dropbox is better

Comment: I've tried your page in IE8, Chrome 21 & Opera 12 so far. Everything works well! Try to clear your cache...

Comment: It works in my systems too(my OS is windows 7) It is not working in windows xp browsers. your OS???

Comment: Win7 as well... What versions of IE do not work for you?

Comment: In my system it works with all the versions of IE. Problem is only in xp system (IE and chrome as well) i guess i have tested in tat so far.

Comment: But, what **versions** of Internet Explorer and Chrome? IE6, IE7 & Chrome 11, Chrome 19...?

Comment: chrome 21.0.1180.89 m... same version in both the sysytems but works with windows 7 but not in xp. same for IE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16584/discussion-between-sowmya-and-yckart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what the issue is, as I can't access the page, but you could try using another of the MANY jQuery Scrollbar plugins. Try [jQuery Scrollbars](http://github.com/nathggns/Scrollbars) for example.